# Ansible: Iteration fails while looping over output variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, json

Here is my debug output from an ansible playbook:

```
    "msg": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "instances": [
            {
                .........
                "private_dns_name": "ip-10-XXX-XXX-XX.ec2.internal", 
                "private_ip_address": "10.XXX.XXX.XX", 
                "product_codes": [], 
                "public_dns_name": "", 
                "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
                "root_device_type": "ebs", 
                "security_groups": ["...."], 
                "source_dest_check": true, 
                ......
                "private_dns_name": "ip-10.XXX.XXX.XX.ec2.internal", 
                "private_ip_address": "10.XXX.XXX.XX", 
                "product_codes": [], 
                "public_dns_name": "", 
                "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1", 
                "root_device_type": "ebs", 
                "security_groups": ["...."], 
                "source_dest_check": true, 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to do partition of disks from the created EC2 instances. `output` variable consists of `IP addresses` in JSON format where I want to loop through each IP address and get the disk information of the server, then I do partition using `parted` module as per below.

```
- name: Collect Disk Information 
      setup:
        gather_subset:
          - hardware
      delegate_to: "{{ output.instances[0].private_ip_address }}"
    
    - name: Print disks Details
      debug:
        var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys()|list
     
    - name: Create Partition
      parted:
        device: "/dev/{{ item }}"
        number: 1
        part_type: 'primary'
        state: present
      delegate_to: "{{ output.instances[0].private_ip_address }}"
      with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() }}"
```

This task can only do partition on the `instances[0]` array, I want to loop through all the `private_ip_address` in the output variable. How to achieve this?

I tried with below as well

**Try 1:**

```
      delegate_to: "{{ item.private_ip_address }}"
      loop: "{{ output.instances }}"
```

Comment: what could be the issue?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to achieve. The loop will override the facts on each iteration. This is not what you want I guess. [edit] your question and make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See the correct syntax in the answer.

Comment: @VladimirBotka, could you look into the question that I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    output:
      instances: [
         {"name": "ip-10", "ip": "10.1.0.10"},
         {"name": "ip-20", "ip": "10.1.0.20"}]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "delegate_to: {{ item.ip }}"
      loop: "{{ output.instances }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'delegate_to: 10.1.0.10'
  msg: 'delegate_to: 10.1.0.20'
```

Comment: actually I am not defining the variable.. ```output``` is the registered variable which comes from ```register```

Comment: I have tried this but I am getting ```"rc": 1```. what could be the cause